# Elastic Load balancer listener not working for one port

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load-balancing, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an Elastic Beanstalk Docker container running a Sinatra app. Using ebextensions, I have an haproxy instance running on the EC2 box - that forwards traffic from port `9090` to the `docker_ip:application_port`. The setup works fine, since I am able to curl the EC2 box's IP on port `9090` and hit my application's endpoints (I am also able to see the haproxy logs)

Now, I have set up an additional tcp listener on Elastic loadbalancer to forward port 9090 to port 9090 (the default is port 80 -> port 80). However when I try to access `domain_name:9090` , it times out. If I just access `domain_name` it works. Any ideas on how I can go about debugging why the load balancer listeners are not working as expected.

Note, the ELB visibility is set to public.

---

So, I turned on logging for the load balancer and accessed it's DNS name directly. It logged the requests sent to port 80, but not the ones sent to port 9090.

---

Another update - I ran a tcpdump on the ec2 box on port 9090. It did not capture any packets where I ran `load_balancer_domain:9090`

---

**Solved** - I had to edit the security group rules on the load balancer to allow outbound traffic on port 9090 for the instance.

Comment: This SO saved my life. Been looking all over for why the load balancer wasn't sending the traffic through to the instance - didn't think to check the _outbound_ traffic rules. THANK YOU!

Comment: In my case, I had added the port to the security group rules, but had only allowed access over IPv6, while I was trying to connect with IPv4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable ELB [Access Logs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/enable-access-logs.html) and send a request to the AWS generated DNS name of the ELB. Check the logfile that the ELB created in the S3 bucket.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion. As I have indicated above, the load balancer logged requests sent to port 80, but not the ones sent to port 9090 :(

Comment: Is your EC2 instance registered with the ELB and `InService`?
Also, does it have to be a TCP listener? Can you not change it to HTTP?

Comment: Yes, it is. Also, I made a small edit in my original question - the default listener (port 80 -> port 80) works. Only the additional listener (port 9090 -> port 9090) fails.

Comment: Check the Security Group of the ELB and the NACL of the VPC to make sure that TCP 9090 is not blocked. [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/elb-security-groups.html)

Comment: Awesome, that fixed it. I had to modify the security group on the load balancer to allow for incoming and outgoing requests on port 9090 !